# webkit browser a:active changing size from a

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar that work fine in Firefox, however in a webit browser the right most button, (the black one) get bigger when clicked, and I cannot work for the life of my why, I have been pouring over the element inspector for well over an hour now, can anyone see the problem?

http://ar.factoryagency.co.uk

Comment: it looks like on click white border of 1 px added to either `a` or `li` or `ul` element inside `of class="ar-nav"`

Comment: cleanup your CSS
something like `border:0 none !important; ` will irritate some browsers.

Comment: In which browser (and version) does this problem accur? Works well in Chrome 18.

Answer (score 0):

```
#top-menu a { border: 0 !important }
```

will fix this problem.